# Uploading App Images: "Invalid GeoJSON: Your routing app coverage file is invalid."

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

This question is not a duplicate to another question that asks about the same message, but in another context. The context of this question is just about uploading screenshot images and getting the message.

Today, I had a new message when uploading images to App Store Connect:

> Invalid GeoJSON: Your routing app coverage file is invalid.

This makes absolutely no sense since, at this time, I had not even chosen a build for the upload.

Retrying to upload the images, it worked. But unfortunately, the message appeared for each language and format.

Is this a bug by Apple or am I missing something? I would guess that uploading images has nothing to do with GeoJSON.

I used Safari. Others seem to have the problem with Chrome. So it occasionally seems to happen on all browsers.

[image: Screenshot of Message]

Comment: It's a bug. Try it with a different browser / VPN. Otherwise contact App Store Connect Developer help.

Comment: Getting same thing - seems to work well for a few minutes in Chrome then fails with this for minutes on end

Comment: @brainray kindly check my answer

Comment: Tried with Chrome and got this bug. Worked when I used Safari.

Answer (score 12):

I had this same problem today while uploading App Store Icon on Preparing for submission page. Solved it by removing "-" from my image name.

Comment: I needed to remove numbers also, I imagine the name must comply with a naming rule related to GeoJSON

Comment: Same issue, I had to remove parenthesis () from my file name

Comment: Unbelievable, it works like a charm. Apple is buggy.

Comment: Worked ... and then it didn't. Now it doesn't matter what the filename is...still getting this error.

Answer (score 10):

This is an unusual bug. Apple might be already working on it. It's not coming on any specific browser. It occurs mostly when we are trying to upload more than one images at once.

Apple always keeps their live site maintenance work active, so this is most likely a bug occurring in their live site maintenance. It will be fixed soon.

For now, if you are finding difficulties handling screenshot uploads, you can try to upload them one by one rather than uploading in a bulk.

**Important Note:**

I am stating this on basis of the last few uploads I have experienced. Also, the solution I have given is tried from my side and it worked for me well. So, you can just try it out and I'm sure that it's not a browser issue. It can occur on any browser.

Comment: I had the same issue. Solved, by changing my browser to Safari from Chrome.

Comment: I have same issue even with Safari and no underscores in name. If I do it again, it is usually accepted.

Comment: Bug is affecting my single file uploads with no special characters in name (i.e. image001.png)

Answer (score 4):

It did not work for me even if I provided English file names. It kept giving the above error.

Only thing that worked for me was to remove all underscores. So instead of `iphone_xs_max_1.png`, it worked when I renamed it to `iphone1.png` and uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure screenshot files name in English.
2. Make sure screenshot files all the directory path(and folder name) in English.

it worked for me.

Comment: doesn't matter what language the screenshot file names are in. spaces and other non-alphanumeric characters are what cause this problem. english, french, german, spanish, portugese, swedish, italian, and every other language that uses the roman alphabet are fine.

n.b. i don't know if accented characters break apple's site. the point remains though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same bug today. Some of the images uploaded without problems, others didn't.

I was uploading in Chrome when I got the issue. Opening the site in Safari and uploading the images there, solved the problem.

Comment: Using Safari fixed it

Answer (score 1):

What solved this for me was removing strings of numbers and periods from the filenames. It appears the system is running the filenames through some kind of geocoder, and if there are strings of characters that could be interpreted as locations, it will error out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure after editing the image you save the file with an extension like myimage.png or myimage.jpg
In my case, I forgot to save the file with extension after removing alpha and transparency properties and no need to change browser etc.